# How to get a Dynamic Component in DXA 1.2

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2

In a JSP page, `Image` and `some text content` is to be loaded based on the user type.

Example : for `userType1` i want to show `image123` and for `userType2` i want to show `image567`.

> Could you help me how to get a Dynamic Component in JSP page using `DXA 1.2` framework?

Comment: See - http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11718/how-to-get-dynamic-component-presentation-on-dxa

Answer (score 4):

Your question is of very low quality, but I'll attempt an answer anyways.

First thing I think you should keep in mind is the way DXA is setup. DXA is an MVC application that uses view models, so we are not talking about Component anymore that you want to retrieve in your views. If you have set your Component Template to be a dynamic one, then from there on you can just consider it as any other item, and you deal with the mapped view model in your views.

If your question is actually about executing a broker query, and retrieving DCPs that way, then I think it makes sense if you edit your question and provide a bit more detail, so you can get more detailed answers too.

Comment: dont we need to use teaser in 1.2?

Comment: @RajKumar why would it, DCPs are mapped to Entities just like "normal" Components are.

Comment: Ok,  if i am recalling correctly, in  1.01 we saw dcp was mapped using teaser only.

Comment: 1.0.1 had no real DCP support, since that was missing in the DD4T version we used. You might be confusing it with the broker query that was executed, that relies on using teasers, but those were not even DCPs

Comment: Got it, we actually modified to support it using broker queries. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

You can see any example in existing DXA code, it works similarl to normal mapping process. Please follow below points.

- Create CT with "Published as a DC" In CMS
- Assign ViewName you want to handle the UI with.
- In View use your View Model
- Apply semantic mapping to View model as per your Schema.
- Debug for any issue.