# How to dynamically change the component in dxa while rendering the component presentations?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, sdl-tridion

Is it possible to change the component that has to be rendered as a component presentation in java dxa 1.2. For example, if an Article component with id `tcm:5-100` is inserted on the page with Article CT.

During the component presentations rendering in delivery, can I replace the existing component with a different Article component with id `tcm:5-101` which I have fetched through broker API based on particular metadata field value.

If it is possible please guide me with the method that has to be extended/ modified if required.

Comment: @Bart pointed out you could get (Dynamic) [Component Presentations using DD4T calls/methods](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/11722/46) in a DXA setup. Would this work for you?

Comment: Thanks Alvin, this article helped me to understand about dd4t api method used to retrieve the component presentation but how can I add this back to the page in place of existing component presentation?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: @Rick, I am looking for this because I want to display user specific article based on a value received from third party service. The value which is received for a user is stored during content creation in article components. I will fetch this matched article component through broker api and I want to display this in place of default article which is inserted on page.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a "personalization" requirement. While you _can_ retrieve a specific (Dynamic) Component Presentation over the the broker or DD4T API, consider how to manage these mappings and avoid relying on hard-coded TCM-URIs, since they may vary across Development to Production environments.

Comment: Yes Alvin. You are right it is personalized content for users. But I am not hardcoding tcm uri, I am fetching tcm uri through broker api based on a value which is received from third party service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Alvin already mentioned, your requirements sound quite similar to what Experience Optimization does; you may want to take a look at the [XO/SmartTarget Module](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/master/webapp-java/dxa-module-smarttarget/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/smarttarget) to see how this kind of functionality is implemented there.

Spoiler: the XO/SmartTarget Module leverages the concept of Regions and can dynamically populate "SmartTarget Regions" with the results from an XO Query; if the query yields no results, it will keep fallback content coming from CM (if any). Technically speaking, the XO/SmartTarget Module uses a so-called *Page Model Builder* to dynamically inject Entity Models in the SmartTarget Region Models.

Another common way to dynamically modify View Models is using a custom Entity Controller. You already mentioned you have a Component Presentation (Entity Model in DXA speak) which represents a placeholder to be personalized. With a custom Entity Controller, you can dynamically post-process this Entity Model (if needed, it can even completely replace the Entity Model with another, based on a dynamic query).

Several DXA Modules have custom Entity Controllers. For example, the Search Module has a [SearchController](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/master/webapp-java/dxa-module-search/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/search/controller/SearchController.java).